# Unwanted jump to top in popup in JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Very annoying behavior in JQuery Mobile 1.4.5

Main page has a DIV with data-role="popup" and a button (simplified).

When the button is clicked, an AJAX call populates the popup DIV with address book entries then popup is triggered.

Each address book entry consists of a label linked to a radio button.

Behavior is as expected when an entry that is visible in the viewport is clicked (click on the label -> radio checked)

The troubles begin when the number of entries make it necessary to scroll down to select the desired entry. As soon as the popup has scrolled, clicking the label makes the whole popup jump back to the top of the viewport, and the desired checkbox does not get checked.

Strange thing is, a button that is all the way under all the address book entries is clickable without page jump.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you have a lot of controls inside your popup, switch to a `page` widget with the `dialog` option (here is the reference: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/pages-dialog/). or use this workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47969063/4845566

Comment: @deblocker : you rock! Your proposal to add a second page and dynamically turn it into a popup worked and saved my bacon. Thanks! (can't seem to be able to give you credit though, as yours is a comment and not an answer?)

Comment: Your feedback is welcome, glad this helped You!